# How to make an email, with content more than 102kB, consistent and regular in Gmail and Yahoo-Mail?

Tags: html, gmail, html-email, email-client, yahoo-mail

I'm trying to send an e-mail containing HTML content. Gmail and Yahoo has a limit of approximately 102kB. The e-mail clients clip/crop the e-mail if the content of the e-mail is above 102kB. However, they provide a link to open the complete e-mail.

I'm trying to understand how this clipping happens as random clipping is problematic for my use-case. The e-mail when clipped looks very ugly and irregular. 
I'm looking for a solution using which I can write the HTML in such a way that even if the e-mail gets clipped, the content doesn't look inconsistent.

Below is a screenshot of an e-mail which got clipped by Gmail:

[image: Email getting clipped by Gmail]

```
<td valign="top">
```

As you can see that the above tag is visible in the email. This is unexpected and I want to remove all such irregularities.

Can someone please suggest a method by which I can make the e-mail consistent even if it gets cropped/clipped?

Note : This question is for scenarios where the size is definitely more than 102kB and the e-mail will surely get clipped.

Thanks!

Comment: @DaImTo this is a question for `html-email`. Here is a link to show what some people from the email community are doing. https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [github page](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/41) that shows different scenarios of testing done to determine the size emails get clipped at. The result was 100 Kb (or 102 Kb on drive).

Summary of the tests from GitHub page:

**Test 1:**
400 tables and 400 style tags.
Test email clipped at the 181th table

**Test 2:**
Only the 400 tables. 
Test email clipped at the 254th table.

**Test 3:**
400 tables (each with an HTML data attribute on each  example: ). 
Test email clipped at the 223rd table

There is no absolute method to keep emails consistent 100% of the time if clipping occurs. In short the tables will gave to be structured in a way that HTML file size is at 100kb/102kb file size for truncating not to occur.

Comment: Hi @Syfer,

Thanks a lot for the different scenarios of testing to determine the clipping email size.

I understand that we've to restrict the size of the email below 100kB to avoid clipping. But due to some reasons, I cannot decrease the content or the size of the HTML document.

Comment: I was wondering if there could be a way to stop the email client from rendering a specific element which it clips abruptly. The midway clipping is a major problem 
and I'm looking for a way to put conditions using which the email client stops rendering. I'm just a beginner in handling HTML emails, so I don't even know if it's even possible.

Comment: Sorry I didn't write that githib page and can not take credit for that. You can encase elements in a table each and use media queries to hide them I would say. Media queries work in all major email clients so you should be able to use them in Yahoo, Outlook and Gmail

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the github page. It was really helpful in understanding the email clipping.

Encasing elements in table and using media queries sounds like a good idea. I'll try to do that and see if it works. Thanks!

I just wanted to ask one more question. I didn't see the email getting clipped in Outlook 365 desktop application. Does Outlook clip the emails in other products 
like Outlook.com or Outlook for Android?

Comment: I haven't come across Outlook clipping yet and managed to stop others as well by keeping the file size down. If this answers your question please select it as the one. If you want to chat, tweet me on syfer_darknight.

Answer (score 1):

This is an email client specific 'feature'. A recent update - perhaps to only some of the latest Gmail Apps - removes this problem.

[image: Gmail app screenshot showing clean cut with message: View entire message]